# assets are precompiled but app still looks for all the separate js files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline

My capistrano is precompiling correctly all the assets in the pipeline, and generating the application.js and application.css files with the complete wrap up.

The problem is that my application is still looking for all the separate .js and .css files, that aren't present on the server, and this generates lots of `404 not found` responses from the nginx server.

the css and javascript are loaded in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` file with:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

and in the `app/assets/javascript/application.js` the components are loaded with:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require jquery.timepicker
//= require colorbox-rails
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

How can I get the app to use only the single precompiled file when the precompile has happened?

thanks,

Comment: Are you sure the app is running in the `production` environment on your server?

Comment: no, it's running on `development` env, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiled assets is a feature of the `production` environment.  In the `development` environment you typically don't want this.  If a line raises an exception, you want to know which file it's in so you can easily it.

This is governed by this line in your `config/environments/*.rb` config files:

```
config.assets.compress = true # or false
```

If `true`, it excepts combined assets.  If `false`, it expects assets in their own files.

In `development` this is typically `false`. In production this is typically `true`.  But either way it's an environment specific setting, so you wont get it to work differently in two places under the same environment.

Perhaps you want to set up a `staging` environment instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am quite unclear about what's the preferred way to use the environments in rails. I thought originally that I could have a vagrant box, deploy to it via capistrano and develop my app directly on such sandboxed system. But now it appears more like I have to develop locally (and install mysql on my laptop), then I could do staging on my vagrant box, and finally deploy to the virtual server for production. Is this the recommended workflow? thanks.

Comment: You are far better off developing with the development server running on your own machine, alongside you code editor. If you want a hosted server that you dont make live edits to, but isn't your full production, it's common to _create_ a new environment named `staging` for that.